# Is this HtmlHelper extension overkill?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I've implemented a custom html helper extension method to render a partial view into my razor page and I'm concerned that the method I've used is "too heavy"...

I want to use a common spinner across my web project.  The spinner I'm using requires a number of elements:

```
<div class="panel-spinner-container">
    <div class="sk-spinner sk-spinner-cube-grid">
        <div class="sk-cube"></div>
        <div class="sk-cube"></div>
        <div class="sk-cube"></div>
        <div class="sk-cube"></div>
        <div class="sk-cube"></div>
        <div class="sk-cube"></div>
        <div class="sk-cube"></div>
        <div class="sk-cube"></div>
        <div class="sk-cube"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-spinner-msg"><p>loading...</p></div>
</div>
```

Rather than including this in razor code every time I want a spinner, I figured I'd toss it into an html helper method, so I could do this:

```
<div>
    @Html.PanelSpinner()
</div>
```

I created a partial view for this which just contains the divs from above, and an html helper extension method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString PanelSpinner(this HtmlHelper html) {

    var controllerContext = html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
    var viewData = html.ViewData;
    var tempData = html.ViewContext.TempData;

    using (var stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter()) {

        var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, "PanelSpinner");
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, viewResult.View, viewData, tempData, stringWriter);

        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);
        var stringResult = stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();

        return new MvcHtmlString(stringResult);
    }
}
```

This seems like an awful lot of processing required to render a spinner.  What is the performance overhead on this type of method?  Is it normal to use a helper for this type of scenario, or am I overkilling this?  Is there a better (more performant) way to do this?

I very much like the ease of use but am concerned about performance (e.g., I could just use `@Html.RenderPartial(...)`, but then I have to remember the name of the spinner partial, etc.  The helper method wrapper is so much easier to use)

Comment: what about use only css?
This guy made spinners only with css http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

Comment: The only thing your appear to need to 'remember' is "PanelSpinner". Your extension method could simply be `public static MvcHtmlString PanelSpinner(this HtmlHelper html) { return html.Partial("PanelSpinner"); }`

Comment: Looks fine to me, this is how a million other things get rendered on your pages, why would yours make things go south? It's not like your spinner is getting rendered once per frame... You get a call to this per spinner, how many spinners are we talking here?

Comment: @Charleh - I wasn't sure if this was the way "a million other things get rendered", so didn't know whether this would be an issue.  I wouldn't think I'd be looking at more than half a dozen spinners per page (and usually only one or maybe two).

Comment: @StephenMuecke - the HtmlHelper doesn't seem to have a `Partial()` method.  That was first thing I thought and finding how to render a partial view for the helper landed me with the code above.

Comment: Of course it does :) I assume you have not included the correct `using System.Web.Mvc.Html;` namespace

Comment: @StephenMuecke - well geez, how about that.  Toss it in an answer and I'll accept it as this seems a much more appropriate route (@Charleh - I'm guessing this rendering of the Partial method does all of my stuff in the background anyway, but the semantics is better to just call the Partial() from the helper - thanks for clearing up the background process for me)

Comment: Yes basically this is the underlying mechanism anyway, but it makes sense to use a partial since you don't have to write the boilerplate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To render a partial view using an extension method, you can make use of the built in `Partial()` method of `HtmlHelper`. It can simply be

```
public static MvcHtmlString PanelSpinner(this HtmlHelper html)
{
    return html.Partial("PanelSpinner");
}
```

Note: You need to include `using System.Web.Mvc.Html;`